# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in Yii 1

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to get multiple selections from user  but after submitting I get the error :

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Books_read'); ?>
<div>
 <?php $opts = array('booka' => 'Book A', 'bookb' => 'Book  B', 'bookc' => 'Book C ', 'bookd' => 'Book D','booke' => 'Book E','bookf' => 'Book F');
    echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'Books_read', $opts, array(
                  'class' => 'checkbox',
                'multipe' => 'multiple',
              'template' => '{input}{label}',
               'separator' => '<br/>',
              'labelOptions' => array('style' =>'margin: 2px 0px 2px 4px;'),
                                        'style' => 'float:left;',)); ?>

        </div>
      <?php echo form->error($model,'Books_read '); ?>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

**datatype in database** : text (works fine for other form)

**model class :**

```
protected function afterFind() {

        if ($this->isJSON($this->Books_read)) 
        {
            $this->Books_read = json_decode($this->Books_read);
        }

        return parent::afterFind();
    }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Yii. But I can tell you that when the dropdown input is set to multiple select the post date is returned as an array. Somewhere in the code its treating the input as a string where the actual date is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Write your form element as below:-

```
echo $form->checkBoxList(
  $model,
 'Books_read',
  $opts,
  'htmlOptions' => array( // add htmlOptions
    'labelOptions' => array(
       // code
    )
  )
);
```